# Disassembling Hello World program in IDA

Tags: windows, assembly, decompiling, ida

I've de-compiled in IDA 7.0 (freeware version) such a simple c program (compiled in the Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h >

char* sayHello(char* resultStr, char* addedStr) {
  strcat_s(resultStr, strlen(resultStr)+strlen(addedStr)+1, addedStr);
  return resultStr;
}

int main() {
  char str_in_1[100] = "Hello"; 
  char str_in_2[] = " World!";

  printf ("%s", sayHello(str_in_1, str_in_2));
}
```

Now i can't find the string `sayHello` (function name) either in the *Functions window* nor in the *IDA View-A*. How to find out where in the disassembled code is the exact code of the `sayHello` function?

Comment: Are you able to locate `main()`? If so, post that and we can take a look at what might be the reference to `sayHello()` from there.

Comment: If you compiled it as release, then you shouldn't find it as a string anway. And most likely it got optimized to inline. I would recommedn to switch on assembler output when compiling, then you can more easily track the code in the binary.

Comment: Is this decompiler output already?  I thought the var names in `main` looked a bit formulaic, but I guess not given the arg names like `resultStr` in the prototype of `sayHello`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, this is IMO the original C code. It doesn't look like decompiled code to me.

Comment: IDA can't have named a function `sayHello` unless you loaded the debug symbols. In this case you'll find `sayHello` in the functions windows. But I think Devolus is right, you expected to get the original program back from the compiled one. That's not how it works :)